# Ember.js: attributeBinding with a '-' fire 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token -'

Tags: ember.js

I need to bind an html input attribute with the 'data-date" name.
I got an error when binding a variable with a '-'. 
It works fine using a "basic" variable name

How can I fix that ?

Code that works (binding test attribute):

```
App.DatePicker = Em.View.extend({
  classNames: ['input-append date'],
  attributeBindings: ['data-date-format', 'test'],
  testBinding: 'this.value',
  value: ''
```

Code that does not work using data-date att name: (fire SyntaxError: Unexpected token - )

```
App.DatePicker = Em.View.extend({
  classNames: ['input-append date'],
  attributeBindings: ['data-date-format', 'data-date'],
  data-date: 'jkljkl',
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but try something like  attributeBindings: ['data-date:dataDate'], dataDate: 'polop'

Comment: I have tested your proposal but it does not work :( .. any other idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, my bad I've inverted the writing.

```
MyApp.DatePicker = Em.View.extend({
  classNames: ['input-append date'],
  attributeBindings: ['dtf:data-date-format', 'dataDate:data-date'],
  dtf: '',
  dataDate: 'jkljkl'
});
```

It seems you must use an empty string in order to leave the attribute wih an empty value.